# Помогите ,пишу запрос и не выводит ничего ,даже ошибки нет ,ничего не меняется

Tags: c#, wpf

int a-это студент в базе ,номер его

private void ButtonPrim_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

```
        int a = 2222;

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Студенты SET НЗачетнойКнижки = @Number,Фамилия = @Fam, Имя= @Ima, Отчество = @Otch , Группа = @groop, Форма_обучения = @forma ,Дата_поступления = @DatePost, Дата_выпуска = @DateVip, Дата_рождения = @DateRoj WHERE НЗачетнойКнижки = @Nnumber ", Connection);

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nnumber", a);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", Convert.ToInt32(Tnumber.Text));
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fam", Tfam.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ima", Tima.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Otch", Totch.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("groop", ComboBoxgroop.SelectedIndex);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("forma", ComboBoxform.SelectedIndex);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DatePost", Datepost.SelectedDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateVip", datevip.SelectedDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateRoj", dateroj.SelectedDate);

        OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Справки SET Студент = @Number, Вид_справки = @Vid, Количество = @Kol Where Студент = @Nnumber", Connection);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", Tnumber.Text);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Vid", ComboBoxVid.SelectedIndex);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Kol", TKol.Text);
        command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nnumber", a);
    }
```

Comment: Вы формируете, но не выполняете запрос, поэтому ничего и не происходит. Добавьте ```command.ExecuteNonQuery()```

Comment: как тебе оценку поставить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void ButtonPrim_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
        {
            int a = 2222;
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Студенты SET НЗачетнойКнижки = @Number,Фамилия = @Fam, Имя= @Ima, Отчество = @Otch , Группа = @groop, Форма_обучения = @forma ,Дата_поступления = @DatePost, Дата_выпуска = @DateVip, Дата_рождения = @DateRoj WHERE НЗачетнойКнижки = @Nnumber ", Connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nnumber", a);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", Convert.ToInt32(Tnumber.Text));
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Fam", Tfam.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Ima", Tima.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Otch", Totch.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("groop", ComboBoxgroop.SelectedIndex);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("forma", ComboBoxform.SelectedIndex);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DatePost", Datepost.SelectedDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateVip", datevip.SelectedDate);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateRoj", dateroj.SelectedDate);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Справки SET Студент = @Number, Вид_справки = @Vid, Количество = @Kol Where Студент = @Nnumber", Connection);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Number", Tnumber.Text);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Vid", ComboBoxVid.SelectedIndex);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Kol", TKol.Text);
            command1.Parameters.AddWithValue("Nnumber", a);
            command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

P.S. читайте комменты, там дельные вещи пишут

P.S.S. будьте внимательнее

Comment: как тебе оценку поставить?

Comment: Отметить ответ правильным, обычно это так делается

Comment: @Roma слева от ответа есть галочка.